# How to do Code Coverage for Fluent NHibernate Mapping files

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to do code coverage for Fluent Nhibernate mappingfiles.Please tell me how to proceed if possible with sample code. I was able to unit test the mapping file using persistence configuration but unable to get code coverage for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get code coverage on the ClassMap mapping classes then simply creating an instance of each class will give you that. I'd question the usefulness of doing that since all it gains you is: "yup, I can create an instance of that class so class constructors in .NET  really work." I'd consider verifying the correctness of the mapping class more important than just exercising its constructor. This [blog post](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/06/19/working-faster-and-fewer-mapping-errors-with-nhibernate/) has some good ideas on verifying mapping classes.

Comment: Using the FluentNHibernate.Testing.PersistenceSpecification class @user1039583 is able to do more than just verify the constructor. The issue he is having is how does he get code coverage analysis to indicate which parts of the mapping he has tested successessfully (that's my understanding imho).

Comment: I guess the question is a bit unclear to me. The point I was trying to make (in a muddled way) is that it more important to verify the correctness of the mapping (which PersistenceSpecification does) than to worry about getting code coverage on the mapping class constructor. Since the code in the mapping class constructor either is all executed or not run at all (if the mapping class is not instantiated), there really isn't a way through code coverage to identify which properties in an entity have been exercised through a PersistenceSpecification unit test.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I think he is better off sticking to PersistenceSpecification tests and not getting too hung up about code coverage on mapping class constructors. It the PersistenceSpecification tests show that his mappings are working correctly he shouldn't need to worry about code coverage stats ;)

Comment: Ryan, You are right. But i need to do unit testing as well code coverage both for the mapping files.